# Command to copy file to remote server with different user ID?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, scp

I would like to transfer file from serverA to serverB. I have access to both the servers so I am logging in to serverA and giving below command to transfer the file

```
scp filename.txt mqm@serverB:/home/akotha/testdir
```

Here `akotha` is my ID and I do have sudo access to `mqm`, after executing the command it should use `mqm` user to transfer the file; but if password requisite/mandatory then it should take my `akotha` user password.

There is any command to achieve it, please let me know if you are not clear with my question.

```
#!/bin/ksh   
echo "please below details to copy to server"
echo "remote server name:" read rserver
echo "user name:" read user
echo "remote location:" read rloc
echo "please enter the complete path to check files:" read dir
echo "enter single or batch file name to copy:" read file
scp  $dir/$file $user@$rserver:$rloc
```

Answer (score 0):

If the you have username/password for serverB, you should use it when you execute the `scp` command.

If you have passwod for user `akotha` on `serverB`, you should use it in the following format:

```
scp filename.txt akotha@serverB:/home/akotha/testdir
```

The following solution will allow write access to folder `serverB:/home/akotha/testdir` by user `akotha`:

- Create a new group which will hold both users (this should be done by `root` user or by using `sudo`)

  For example, use mqmakotha as group name, and the group should hold both users.

  This link shows [How to add users to group](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/)
- Change the group of the `/home/akotha/testdir` folder to be this group

  `chgrp mqmakotha /home/akotha/testdir`
- Change the permission of `/home/akotha/testdir` to be group read/write-able

  `chmod g+rw /home/akotha/testdir`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Yes i have password for akotha user but the location "/home/akotha/testdir" will accept only mqm user to place the files.

I have sudo access (i.e sudo su - mqm) to switch to mqm user but no password. when i want to copy the files then it should copy with mqm user and ask akotha password.

Comment: @amarnadhmanikanta - I've updated my answer with instructions how to allow user `akotha` to write to folder owned by user `mqm` using a shared group.

Comment: Actually here i am creating one shell script  (updated the whole script in the question) to copy files from one server to other...... i do not have any access to create group or delete folder, files or directory other than sudo to mqm...... so my requirement is to copy files with mqm user and while copying i should be able to enter my akotha password but not mqm...

Comment: @amarnadhmanikanta If the source of the problem is that you are logging as userA, and would like to write in a folder owned by userB, the solution of a shared group will solve your problem.

Comment: shared group is good solution but as per our project SLA breach we do not have permissions to created groups or any other activity..... :(

Comment: Can you place the files in a write-able location of the account which you use for login (or scp)? i.e. the account with a password?

Comment: yes i can place the files